# Why make a parameter const if you're going to do const_cast?

Tags: c++

There was a linked list example where someone was trying to append a node. This is part of the code:

```
void Append(ListElement<T> const* ptr, T const& datum)
{
    ListElement<T>* temp = const_cast<ListElement<T>*>(ptr);
    // ...
}
```

What is the point in making `ptr` a pointer to `const` if you're going to just cast it away? `ptr` isn't used anywhere in the function, just `temp`, so wouldn't it be better to make it a pointer to *non*-const so people know that the object might be modified?

Is there a reason to make a parameter `const` and then `const_cast`'ing it away in the body instead of just making it non-const?

Comment: answer: poor design. (The only real reason is to pass temp to a legacy library that doesn't support const but you know for sure that it is const).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the point in making `ptr` a pointer to `const` if you're going to just cast it away?

#### None.

It breaks the function contract and is an example of someone getting lost in code design.

---

To illustrate, it would look like this

- A: Hey, you can read from that object, but only read.
- B: Okay, give me it, I'm going to only read from it.
- B: *writes on it*

Comment: Are there valid reasons to use `const_cast`?

Comment: @templateboy That's a whole another question. As @IdeaHat pointed out, you might have a legacy API where you are guaranteed by informal spec that the function won't write on the object, but it's not expressed in the interface. Then your function effectively *becomes* a `const_cast`. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used).

Answer (score 7):

poor design. If the code is never used, then this is just simply bad practice and you should fire the programmer that did it out of a canon.

The one instance it happens (and why there is a const_cast in the first place) is that if you have a legacy 3rd party library (especially c libraries) that don't define const (or to interface your const correct code with someone's not const correct code). It would still be a terrible design imho to leave that reference around.

```
 int legacy(int* const_no_really_i_swear);

 int my_new_func(const int* var)
 {
     //way 1 (non-const reference goes out of scope immediately)
     legacy(const_cast<int*>(var));

     //way 2 (non-const reference goes out of scope at end of block
     {
        int* temp = const_cast<int*>(var);
        legacy(temp);
     }
 }
```

Using this in code it just bad and will most likely lead to undefined behavior, especially around strict aliasing rules.

Edit: I should specify that you can and should only do this if you really know what your doing. You can never make the guarentee that `legacy` doesn't mess with `temp`. If you have access to the code it is better to refactor it to be const correct than do this, (this is why some people don't like `const` as it is infectious, but I look at that as one of its features!)